# c++ gcc5 and 4.9 linking

Tags: gcc, linker, static-linking

I installed gcc5 on a machine with system wide libraries compiled with gcc 4.9.
In particular `boost` has been compiled with the older gcc4.9 compiler.
I would expect to have linking problems, but compiling and linking a simple program that depends on `libboost_system` and `libboost_filesystem` doesn't show any problem.

I thought gcc5 would break binary compatibility with previously built libraries, and I wonder if I might end up having some weird behavior in my executables with this configuration.

The installed libstdc++ is: `libstdc++.so.6.0.13`

Would it be a problem is I am linking for instance some simple program like this:

```
//gcc5 main
int main()
{
  auto a = func();
}

//gcc 4.9 library linked statically or dinamically
std::string func
{
  std::string s;
  //do something
  return s;
}
```

Can you explain me why it links correctly?

Comment: If you are referring to the `libstdc++` ABI break, then that depends only on the installed `libstdc++`.  If that's the 4.9 one, there's no problem.  Similarly, if you configured `gcc`/`libstdc++` with `--disable-libstdcxx-dual-abi`, there's not issue.

Comment: yes I am referring to that. libstd version is `libstdc++.so.6.0.13`. I thought there would be problems if, for example, an `.so` or object file linked in statically, compiled with gcc4.9 would return a string object to the executable compiled with gcc5.